# bash no parameters for $(function parameters)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, devops

I want to create a script that use basic (prompt and confirm) functions multiple times, when I try to set the return to any variable the function ignore the parameters

```
function promp() {
    echo $*
    read response
    echo $response
}
function confirm() {
    echo $*
    read -rp $'(y/N) : ' -ei $'N' key;
    case "$key" in
        [yY][eE][sS]|[yY])
            echo true
            ;;
        *)
            echo false
            ;;
    esac
}

IS_RESPONSE=$(confirm "SOME QUESTION")
STRING_RESPONSE=$(promp "WRITE SOMETHING")
echo $IS_RESPONSE
echo $STRING_RESPONSE
```

### Expected:

```
SOME QUESTION
(y/N) : N
WRITE SOMETHING 
#<< "some text"
false
some text
```

### Obtained:

```
(y/N) : N
#<< "some text"
SOME QUESTION false
WRITE SOMETHING some text
```

I know the problem is the echo within the function is part of the variable data, but I want to get this printed.

How can I do this or which is the best way to do this

Comment: You capture all  the output from the functions in the variables, so nothing is going to be output until you echo the vars. You can write directly to the tty with `echo "$*" > /dev/tty` though, which is what I think you may want.

Comment: Note that you should use `echo "$*"` rather than the unquoted form (but `$*` is probably more appropriate than `echo "$@"` as you are echoing a single string).

Comment: @123: You should turn your comment into an answer. I think this is the best solution so far. I happen to have the same problem, and it's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the answer of @123, @ruslan and @chepner I made this:

```
function prompt() {
  printf '%s\n' "$1" > /dev/tty
  read "$2"
  echo $response
}
function confirm() {
  local key
  printf '%s\n' "$1" > /dev/tty
  read -rp $'(y/N) : ' -ei $'N' key;
  case "$key" in
    [yY][eE][sS]|[yY]|[sS][iIíÍ]|[sS])
      key=true
      ;;
    *)
      key=false
      ;;
  esac
  if [[ "$2" ]]; then
    printf -v "$2" "$key"
  else
    echo "$key"
  fi
}
```

### quick test for functions execution

```
$(confirm "SOME QUESTION") && echo "it works"
confirm "SOME OTHER QUESTION" IS_RESPONSE
prompt "WRITE SOMETHING" STRING_RESPONSE
echo $IS_RESPONSE
echo $STRING_RESPONSE
```

Answer (score 3):

Your functions are called in context of [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html#FTN.AEN7205):

```
STRING_RESPONSE=$(promp "WRITE SOMETHING")
```

So the standard output of the `promp "WRITE SOMETHING"` command is attached to the context of the variable assignment.

However, the standard error is still attached to the terminal. If you redirect the output of `echo` to the file descriptor `2`, then the output will be displayed to the user just when the `echo` is called, e.g.:

```
function promp() {
    echo >&2 "$*"
    read response
    echo "$response"
}
```

Another way is to use `-p` option: `read -p "Your prompt: "` which [prints the prompt string to the standard error](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/read.def?h=bash-4.4#n528) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Global variables are used more commonly in shell scripts than other languages; if your code is getting too complicated to easily manage global variables, it is probably time to switch to another language anyway.

```
# This is probably too trivial to even define as a function.
promp() {
    read -p "$1" "$2"
}

confirm() {
    printf '%s\n' "$1" >&2
    read -rp $'(y/N) : ' -ei N key
    case "$key" in
        [yY][eE][sS]|[yY])
            key=true
            ;;
        *)
            key=false
            ;;
    esac
    printf -v "$2" "$key"
}

# No expensive command substitutions needed;
# read and printf -v will both populate a global variable
# named by an argument.
confirm "SOME QUESTION" IS_RESPONSE
promp "WRITE SOMETHING" STRING_RESPONSE
echo "$IS_RESPONSE"
echo "$STRING_RESPONSE"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the prompts in the `read` commands instead of `echo`:

```
#!/bin/bash
function promp() {
    read -p "$*"$'\n' response
    echo $response
}
function confirm() {
    read -rp "$*"$'\n'"(y/N) : " -ei $'N' key
    case "$key" in
        [yY][eE][sS]|[yY])
            echo true
            ;;
        *)
            echo false
            ;;
    esac
}

IS_RESPONSE=$(confirm "SOME QUESTION")
STRING_RESPONSE=$(promp "WRITE SOMETHING")
echo $IS_RESPONSE
echo $STRING_RESPONSE
```

Results:

```
$ ./test.sh
SOME QUESTION
(y/N) : N
WRITE SOMETHING
something
false
something
```